# Console.Write and Console.WriteLine in Visual Basic does not appear in console output

Tags: vb.net

Tried to make a simple condition in Visual Basic but `Console.write` and `Console.WriteLine` does not appear in the Console Window, already set the output to *Console Application*

```
Sub Main()

    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("**Kalkulator Hitung Nilai Menggunakan Console Aplication**")

    Dim Tugas As Integer
    Dim UTS As Integer
    Dim UAS As Integer
    Dim T As Double
    Dim txtHuruf As Char

    Console.Write("Masukan Nilai Tugas = ")
    Tugas = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Masukan Nilai UTS = ")
    UTS = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Masukan Nilai UAS = ")
    UAS = Console.ReadLine()

    T = (Tugas * 0.2) + (UTS * 0.5) + (UAS * 0.3)

    If T > 85 Then
        Console.Write("A")
    ElseIf T > 70 Then
        Console.Write("B")
    ElseIf T > 50 Then
        Console.Write("C")
    ElseIf T > 30 Then
        Console.Write("D")
    ElseIf T > 0 Then
        Console.Write("E")
    End If

End Sub
```

The console does output the `Input` but does not output every `Console.WriteLine`

The program closed after this:
[image: Input] and does not show the remaining output, using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: There is a difference between VB and VBA. Your tags don't make clear which one you refer to. In VBA `Console` isn't a recognized object. You would use `Debug.Print` to write to the Immediate Window.

Comment: Your code is VB.NET not VBA.

Comment: Please post code and not images of code. did you try setting a breakpoint and inspecting the value of your inputs and the calculated `T`? Is there an exception happening? Maybe you input some value that can't be parsed into an integer?

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`; you're assigning strings to integers

Comment: I suggest you put an `Else` and also put a `Console.ReadLine()` as the last line of your program to stop it ending until you've had chance to read the output

Comment: This is a stright debugging issue.  clearly you've not checked you code.  As Caius Jard has said, your doing math on string variable, which is resulting in none of you if conditions being satisfied and hence, no WriteLine is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put Console.ReadXxx() as the last line in your program.

```
    If T > 85 Then
        Console.Write("A")
    ElseIf T > 70 Then
        Console.Write("B")
    ElseIf T > 50 Then
        Console.Write("C")
    ElseIf T > 30 Then
        Console.Write("D")
    ElseIf T > 0 Then
        Console.Write("E")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey() ' Or Console.ReadLine() / Console.Read()
```

Console.ReadKey() waits for any key.

Console.Read() and Console.ReadLine() waits for 'Enter' key.